# Error occurred during deployment javax.ejb.CreateException

Tags: glassfish, ejb

When I deploy the application shows me this error

[image]

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@Singleton
public class ConfiguratorBean {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ConfiguratorBean.class);
    @PersistenceContext(unitName= "parqueosPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public PConfiguracion findConfiguracionById(String parametro) {
        return em.find(PConfiguracion.class, parametro);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        log.info("Configurado ambiente para desarrollo");
        PConfiguracion conf = findConfiguracionById(Configuracion.AMBIENTE_WEB_SERVICES.getParametro());

        if (conf == null) {
            log.error("conf es null");
            return;
        }

        configureSDK(gt.gob.mp.siamp.utilities.sdk.enums.AmbienteSDK.valueOf(conf.getValor()));
    }

    private void configureSDK(
        gt.gob.mp.siamp.utilities.sdk.enums.AmbienteSDK ambienteWsDr) { //servicios administrativos EmpleadosWsSDK empSDK = new EmpleadosWsSDK(); empSDK.configurarAmbiente(ambienteWsDr); DependenciasResponsablesWsSDK ws = new DependenciasResponsablesWsSDK();
        ws.configurarAmbiente(ambienteWsDr);
        log.debug(String.format("EmpleadosWsSDK: %s", empSDK.getAmbienteConfigurado()));
        log.debug(String.format("DependenciasResponsablesWsSDK: %s", ws.getAmbienteConfigurado()));
    } // @PostConstruct // void configure() {
    // EmpleadosWsSDK empleadosSDK = new EmpleadosWsSDK(); // empleadosSDK.configurarAmbiente(AmbienteSDK.CERTIFICACION); // // DependenciasResponsablesWsSDK dependenciasSDK = new DependenciasResponsablesWsSDK(); // dependenciasSDK.configurarAmbiente(AmbienteSDK.CERTIFICACION);
    // } }
}
```

Comment: What is the server version? GlassFish 4.1.1 (if you happened to use it) is buggier than GlassFish 4.1 especially, the GUI tool is not in a usable condition at all.

Comment: Please add the content of the `server.log` to the question.

Comment: This is an ejb exception but you tagged it jsf. I corrected the tags

Comment: You should provide the error message as text, not as an image - images aren't readily searchable.